# innerHTML in external PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, html, innerhtml

I'm trying to change the text within a P tag from an external PHP file. Is there someway I can use innerHTML?

currently this is the line of code I'm trying to use but it doesn't seem to work

```
echo '<script>document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = "test";</script>';
```

I tried just doing

```
document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = "test";
```

However it also doesn't seem to work, I also tried the echo without the script tags

Comment: by "external PHP file," do you mean a file on a website? Or just one on a server somewhere?

Comment: So you are including your external PHP file and you would like to change the external loaded content via javascript?

Comment: Try echo '<script>alert('works!!!');</script>';

Answer (score 1):

To use javascript extenal php, u have to check  alreadywindow loaded (document.ready function in Jquery).

In your case, you have to use window.load function and give the text text change inside that.

Basically php loaded first than javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Using innerHTML, you can change text within a page, if you want to add anything from external php page, you need to use AJAX for loading it.